# Upgrading Kubuntu from 14.04 Final Beta to Stable

Tags: kubuntu, 14.04

I am using Kubuntu's final beta for 14.04 and was wondering if I will have to install 14.04 stable (when released) or will there be a simple upgrade, or maybe just a dist-upgrade?

Comment: Thank you.  I search but didn't see that.

Comment: I did several upgrades like that, but this time it looks scary: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` says - `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jockey-common jockey-kde kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard kde-window-manager kde-workspace kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-full
  playonlinux wine wine1.4 wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386`.

Comment: hmmm... i ran that command and it isnt doing anything... says im up to date but im still on 13.10... I would love an answer...